# How to add carbon fiber to cars?

Tags: materials, uv, texture-painting

I am modeling Koenigsegg One and want to texture it like shown below:

[image]

Right now I am clueless on how I should approach this. Should I model the carbon fiber parts separately and stick it on top of the base mesh? Or should I UV Unwrap those parts and assign the carbon material to it?

What is the ideal way to texture something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the cycles material car thread on Blenderartists and see if you can adapt soe of the materials from there - then you could just assign as needed to parts of the mesh directly, or use a black and white image uv mapped to the mesh as a stencil between node trees, combining materials into one tree. https://blenderartists.org/t/car-paint-materials-iridescent-layers-carbon-fiber-leather/536803/108?u=craig_jones

Answer (score 1):

you need to unwrap your mesh and then export the uv layout to png,jpg image at 2048 px or more higher resolution and edit the image in photoshop or gimp and then paint accurately in where you want

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely UV unwrap and apply a texture to it. You can for instance download a texture set from the internetz or create them by yourself.

If you want to do them your self I would have built a tiling geometry and baked normals from that.

The Principled BSDF shader have both Anisotropic and Clearcoat so you should be able to get good results.

https://www.textures.com/download/pbr0145/133180?q=carbon+fibre